# Let users access remote h2o flow instance to make real-time predictions

Tags: h2o

I would like to let users make single predictions in real time (where they enter the features themselves) using a model saved to a remote `h2o flow` instance. Is there any way to do this or something like this?

I have a trained model saved to a remote `h2o flow` instance and would like to give other users on my local network the ability to go to the `h2o` instance url in their web browsers and make single predictions based on features that they input themselves (ie. not based on a .csv or .hex file uploaded to the flow instance). Basically, the ideal situation would be if h2o flow had some higher level web interface where you could just 'hook up' a model and enter in fill in boxes for different feature values and hit a button to get a prediction on those features. Is there anything remotely like this or a similar workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are really looking is to "how to put H2O models in production?" You really need to understand few key things about H2O models and how to use them in a production system, starting from [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/productionizing.html).

H2O have 3 types of models where Binary (Type:1) must need H2O to perform prediction. The H2O uses RESTful interface so you can use a very simple front end to send your prediction data over RESTful interface to H2O running server and get the prediction back. This all can be done just by using simple JavaScript code.

Other 2 types, POJO (Type:2) and MOJO(type:3) does not need H2O, instead you just need Java runtime i.e. Java App, Java WebServer, Jetty embedded webserver, to perform the prediction. You can learn POJO in production [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/POJO_QuickStart.md) and MOJO in production [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/MOJO_QuickStart.md).

We also have a full Web Application sample "[Consumer Loan Application](https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan)" already built for users to learn how to build a full WebApp using POJO or MOJO. You can clone the following github repo to just compile and run it. Once you got it understood, just use your own POJO/MOJO model to create the Web Front end.

https://github.com/h2oai/app-consumer-loan

There is another way to quickly create a WebApp for your H2O POJO and MOJO models and the option is to use H2O [Steam](https://github.com/h2oai/steam) product and within this product there is "[Steam Prediction Service Builder](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/tree/master/prediction-service-builder)". Please visit the Steam Prediction service builder documentation to use your POJO or MOJO to build a WebApp interface to generate prediction in few minutes.

So you can see there are several ways you can try to  build the WebApp you are looking for.